# How to get values from complex multidimensional arrays in PHP and turn them into strings

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've very complex array that I would like to get values for HTML creation.

I have in my array a list of jpg files in directories, but I want all the files from 'materialy-do-plis' directory that have subdirectories with files and sometimes even more subsubdirectories with more files.

I would like to get in foreach array a nicely generated urls with directory names and files at the end.

And this is my code to get it, if that helps:

```
function pathToArray($path , $separator = '/') {
    if (($pos = strpos($path, $separator)) === false) {
        return array($path);
    }
    return array(substr($path, 0, $pos) => pathToArray(substr($path, $pos + 1)));
}


$dir = APPPATH.'../media/multimedia/obrazy/materialy-do-plis/';
$results = array();
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    foreach ( new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $file ) {
        if ($file->isFile()) {
            $thispath = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);
            $thisfile = utf8_encode($file->getFilename());
            $results = array_merge_recursive($results, pathToArray($thispath));
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);

array_walk($products, function ($value, $key) use ($stores, &$array) {
    $array[$value['store']][] = $value['product'];
});

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically I think, you need a recursing function. 
This function could write to a result array, that might either be a class variable or passed in by reference.

Basically like this (untested, but to get the idea):

```
class Foo {
    private $results = array();

    function recurse($inputArray, $path) {
        foreach($inputArray as $i => $item) {
            if(is_dir($path."/".$i)) {
                $this->recurse($item, $path."/".$i);
            }elseif(is_file($path."/".$item)){
                $this->results[] = $path."/".$item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```